# decimal notation using G29

Tags: c#

I am using G29 for removing two trailoring zeros.

```
 decimal d = 48.90000000M;                
 Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("G29"));
```

Output : 48.9

But my requirement is 48.90.
How to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use String.Format()?

Comment: @GopeshSharma When you're only converting one item, I'd expect `ToString` to be more efficient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd imagine you want `F2` (if you always want two decimal places), not `G29`.

Comment: It's worth noting that F2 performs a Math.Round on the number before reporting it to two decimal places, e.g. 19.445 will become 19.45 To truncate to 2DPs without rounding use Math.Truncate(100 * VALUEGOESHERE) / 100

Answer (score 5):

G converts the number to its *most compact form*; Use F to have the trailing zero.

After all the most compact form of 48.9000000M is 48.9.

From Microsoft Docs:

> The general ("G") format specifier converts a number to the most
> compact of either fixed-point or scientific notation, depending on the
> type of the number and whether a precision specifier is present. The
> precision specifier defines the maximum number of significant digits
> that can appear in the result string. If the precision specifier is
> omitted or zero, the type of the number determines the default
> precision, as indicated in the following table.
> [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#GFormatString)

Comment: Where's the "following table"? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("F"));
```